# Issue certificate through CA that contains a different domain in it?

Tags: certificates

Suppose I own the `whynot.com` domain. Can I request a certificate for `google.com\0x.whynot.com` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `google.com\0x.whynot.com` is not a valid hostname you should not by able to get a certificate for it.  But it was possible once to misuse null characters like you attempt. For more details see [Black Hat 2009: Breaking SSL With Null Characters](http://hackaday.com/2009/07/29/black-hat-2009-breaking-ssl-with-null-characters/).

Comment: Thank you. It's not possible because how the SSL name encoding or browser's way of interpreting strings was changed or because CA's validate the name more accurately ?  from the linked page "The CA ignores the subdomain"

Comment: @adam86: both the validation in the browsers and the CA's was enhanced to make sure to accept only valid names.